# NotificationCenter.default.publisher called from child views in NavigationView hierarchy SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, combine, notificationcenter

## Code

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification))
```

## Current Behaviour:

Above code gets executed for every view in my hierarchy.

## Question:

How can I receive `keyboardWillShowNotification` only for a specific view

Comment: If the current view is updated with an `onReceive`, all views within that view body are also updated.

Comment: I changed my question. @George_E

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by "for a specific view"? Notification has broadcast nature, and `.onReceive` is a handler to that notification, which view do you attach it to does not matter.